# How can I append some angular elements to a div without doing dom manipulations in the controller?

Tags: angularjs

There is a div with some id say mainDiv. And then there are three buttons. Clicking on each button appends a different angular element with different directives to the mainDiv.

```
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
<button ng-click="appendSomeElement1ToMainDiv()"></button>
<button ng-click="appendSomeElement2ToMainDiv()"></button>
<button ng-click="appendSomeElement3ToMainDiv()"></button>
```

How can I achieve this without using dom manipulations in controller. Its too tempting to use

```
$scope.appendSomeElement1ToMainDiv = function () {
  var element1 = angular.element("<p>I am a new element</p>");
  $("#mainDiv").append(element1);
};
```

Comment: What you want to add?

Comment: sample code is far too primitive without more detailed explanation of objectives and source of new element

Comment: I want to add some angular element. Eg. After clicking button1, the mainDiv will look like this: <div id="mainDiv"><element1></element1></div>. I wanted to explain the question in simple terms.

Comment: simple terms is not what's required...should explain your objectives concisely so it is clear to all. For example if adding elements based on scope data or not

Comment: Sorry I disappointed you Charlie, I will try to edit and elaborate my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) are what you are looking for. You can do something like this:

```
myApp.directive('mainArea', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div>"+
            "<div id='mainDiv'> </div>" +
            "<button data-ng-click='append()'>Add</button>" +
        "</div>",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.append = function() {
                var p = angular.element("<p />");
                p.text("Appended");
                $element.find("div").append(p);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And in your HMTL:

```
<main-area></main-area>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1228/)

If your element is a directive, you should take a look at [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I thought of using directive like this but that might complicate things in this case. As I already have a lot of code as a template in another directive. Is there any other way out which wont require me to put all the code as a template in a new directive.

Comment: @watsgoing You can put the template in a HTML file and use the templateUrl property as follows: `templateUrl: path/to/template.html`

Comment: I think I will have to go with this solution if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to append certain data on button click, you could have a array on scope which is changed on button click.Bind this model to the view.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <p ng-repeat="el in elements">{{el}}</p>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="appendSomeElement1ToMainDiv()">b1</button>
        <button ng-click="appendSomeElement2ToMainDiv()">b2</button>
        <button ng-click="appendSomeElement3ToMainDiv()">b3</button>
    </div>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.elements = [];
    $scope.appendSomeElement1ToMainDiv = function() {
        $scope.elements.push('el1');
    }
    $scope.appendSomeElement2ToMainDiv = function() {
        $scope.elements.push('el2');
    }
    $scope.appendSomeElement3ToMainDiv = function() {
        $scope.elements.push('el3');
    }
});
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q3Cgj/

Comment: This one is close. But I need to create different elements on the fly. What you did was added data {{e1}} to the element on button click. `<p ng-repeat="e1 in elements">{{e1}}</p>`. Only 'p' element can be created on all three button clicks by this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom directives, but it depends on the semantics of the button clicks in you application. If they are related only to view logic then directives are the way to go. On the other hand, if they are manipulating the model/scope then I would use the built in ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if directives to show/hide or conditionally insert or remove the DOM elements by binding to model properties that are manipulated by the buttons.